# How to directly upload images to my Images library, without the need to update the properties of the documents?

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, image, enterprise-wiki

I am working on a publishing site collection using the enterprise wiki template. Add when I want to add a new Picture from my Pc to the wiki page, I will be prompted with the following dialog:-

[image]

So can anyone advice if it is possible to bypass this dialog and directly add the imag to the wiki page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent a second Images dialog from being displayed when adding a item to my Images library](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114220/prevent-a-second-images-dialog-from-being-displayed-when-adding-a-item-to-my-ima)

Comment: You've already asked exactly that question [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114220/prevent-a-second-images-dialog-from-being-displayed-when-adding-a-item-to-my-ima?rq=1). How is this question different?

Comment: but i did not get any answers ,, so i remove the old question

Comment: You removed it just NOW. If you did not get answers, you could put a bounty on the question to attract attention, instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Script Editor web part and include the below script on EditForm.aspx library file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Redirect");
function Redirect() {
    var mode = getURLParam('Mode');
    /*  var sourceURL = getURLParam('Source');      
     var  properSourceURL = replaceCharacters(sourceURL);    */
    if (mode == "Upload")
        window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, 'saved');
    /* window.location = properSourceURL;*/
}
function getURLParam(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
function replaceCharacters(str) {
    str = str.replace(/%20/g, " ");
    str = str.replace(/%2F/g, "/");
    str = str.replace(/%3A/g, ":");
    str = str.replace(/%2E/g, ".");
    return str;
}
```

You can edit the EditForm.aspx using browser :
[image]

Comment: where i should edit the form , using SharePoint designer ?

Comment: refer the edited answer

Comment: i think that i can not edit the edit form as i am using enterprise wiki and not a document library. so i added the code inside the EnterpriseWiki.aspx page layout , but it will not prevent the dialog from being displayed ,, can you advice please ?

Comment: enable publishing feature and check.

Comment: i already have the publishing site collection feature enabled,, but when i add a new wiki page i will be loading the EnterPriseWiki page layout and not the defualt edit form ... enterprise wiki works in this way i think

Comment: i think Edit page has to do nothing with the Wiki site. its based on basic list form.

Comment: so if i go to "form Web Parts"--> "Default Edit Form", i will go to the defualt edit form , while when i add/edit a wiki page i use the enterprisewiki page layout ,,, this edit form will not be used ..

Comment: No. It would use the library edit form. have you tried editing the EditForm from UI using the ribbon?

Comment: yes i just did that then i added a web part of type script editor , copy your scrip ,, but this did not prevent the dialog ...

Comment: no idea. its working at my end.strange :(

Comment: are you sing sharepoint 2013 & enterprise wiki site collection ?

Comment: i even add an alert('test') insdie the script , but it will never fire

Comment: i am using enterprise publishing site collection.

Comment: now i added the script inside the edit form & inside the enterprisewiki page layout. and also i added two different alerts inside them;  alert('from edit') & alert('from page layout') . and when i add/edit/view a wiki page i will get an alert from the script that was added to the page layout only... which means that the edit form will not be called ,, and in all cases the Script inside the page layout did not prevent the dialog !!!